# How to show the ellipsis when it reach the maximum space of the container

Tags: html, css

I know how to use text-overflow ellipsis at the when I have only want to show one line text. like this

[image]

which I simply use

```
<div style="height: 36px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 246px;
">
<a>Kesong Xie: </a>
<span class="">This place i have been to before, and it has a nice sunset and a beautiful beach :)</span>
</div>
```

However, the text get truncated when it reaches the end of the first line, while the outside container still gets plenty of space , what I want is something like this:

[image]

It's possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some trickery with the ::after pseudo element

```css
.clip-text{
    position: relative;
}
.clip-text::after{
    position:absolute;
    right:-1px;
    bottom:0;
    content:"..."
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-text" style="height: 36px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 246px;
">
<a>Kesong Xie: </a>
<span class="">This place i have been to before, and it has a nice sunset and a beautiful beach :)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, interesting. What browser are you using?

Comment: I totally misread your question dude, I have updated my answer with something that works.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with CSS. You will have to split the lines into different elements, or use Javascript to achieve that.